# find the attribute 'src' and add 'autoplay=1' in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I want to find the src in iframe and add `autoplay=1` in jquery.I want to find the src which is in iframe and have to add `autoplay=1`,now I doesn't find src and append `autoplay=1`

```
$('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe").contents().find("src").append($("&autoplay=1"));
```

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".playButton").on('click',function(){
    $('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe").contents().find("src").append($("&autoplay=1"));
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playButton">Play</div>
<div class="flex-active-slide">
<iframe src=""> <!--But refering this-->
  #document
   <html>
      <body>
        <iframe src=""><!--want to refer this iframe -->
          #document
           <html>
              <body>

              </body>
           </html>
        </iframe>
      </body>
   </html>
 <iframe>
   </div>
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to jquery documentation for the Attr() method
https://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
$("yourElement").attr('src', 'your-src');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find specific elements from iframe and append autoplay to it
For e.g. I have used video tag as sample

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".playButton").on('click',function(){
        $('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe").contents().find("video").each(function(){
          var videosrc=$(this).attr("src")+"&autoplay=1";
          $(this).attr("src",videosrc);
        });
    });
});
```